# Creating and sorting table by column using underscore.js and knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, underscore.js, tablesorter

First of all, i'm new to Knockout.js and underscore.js, and this is my first day of learning those libraries. The task is to sort table by clicking column header in ascending order on first click, and in descending order on second click.

I have this kind of HTML markup:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: columnNames">
            <td data-bind="text: $data, click: $root.sortColumn, css: { 'active': $root.currentItem() == $data }"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: persons">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: formattedAge"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: sex"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: married"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this js code for knockout.js:

```
function personViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.currentItem = ko.observable('');
    self.columnNames = ko.observableArray([
                'Name',
                'Age',
                'Sex',
                'Married'
    ]);
            self.persons = ko.observableArray([...]);
            self.sortColumn = function(item)
    {
        self.currentItem(item);
        var sorted = _(self.persons()).sortBy(item.toLowerCase());
        self.persons(sorted);
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new personViewModel());
```

Now the question is:

Is it possible to get element descriptor, while one of td's clicked, so i could use something like '$(this)' in self.sortColumn?
Because now i can sort a table by clicking appropriate column header, but i don't know how to mark a column, that it already was clicked (and check it), to use `_(self.persons()).sortBy(item.toLowerCase()).reverse()`, to sort it in descending order of columns.

Thanks:)

Comment: add a click event for the  td`s (use a commonn class for the td).now add a callback function for this event in js which would do your job,like highlighting the respective td(by changing colour or style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is simple. Right now you saving only column name, you need also have variable for sort direction, and your logic in sortColumn would be:

```
 function personViewModel()
 {
     var self = this;
     self.currentItem = ko.observable('');
     self.sortDirection = ko.observable(true);
     self.columnNames = ko.observableArray([
            'Name','Age','Sex','Married'
     ]);
     self.persons = ko.observableArray([
         { name : "John", formattedAge:27, sex:"Male", married:"No"},
         { name : "Bob", formattedAge:30, sex:"Male", married:"Yes"}           
     ]);

     self.sortColumn = function(item)
     {
         if (item == self.currentItem()) {
             self.sortDirection(!self.sortDirection())   
         } else{            
             self.currentItem(item);
             self.sortDirection(true)
         }
         if( self.sortDirection() ) {
             var sorted = _(self.persons()).sortBy(item.toLowerCase());
             self.persons(sorted);
         } else {
             var sorted = _(self.persons()).sortBy(item.toLowerCase()).reverse();
             self.persons(sorted);            
         }
     };
 };

 ko.applyBindings(new personViewModel());
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/vnwZJ/11/) with working example.

Also notice that you don't really need underscore.js here, as ko.js provides you with

```
myObservableArray.reverse()

myObservableArray.sort()
```

Everything you need.

```
var sortDirection = true
self.sortColumn = function(item) {
   if (item == self.currentItem()) {
      sortDirection = !sortDirection
      self.persons.reverse()
   } else {
      sortDirection = true
      var field = self.currentItem()
      self.persons.sort(function(left, right) { 
           return left[field] == right[field] ? 0 
              : ( left[field]< right[field] ? -1 : 1 ) 
      })
   }
}
```